# setting the first value of a groupby to Nan

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a timeseries for different categories

```
cat date        price
A   2000-01-01  100
A   2000-02-01  101
...
A   2010-12-01  140
B   2000-01-01  10
B   2000-02-01  10.4
...
B   2010-12-01  11.1
...
Z   2010-12-01  13.1
```

I need to compute returns on all assets, which is very quick using

```
df['ret'] = df['price'] / df['price'].shift(1) - 1
```

However, that also computes incorrect returns for the first element of each company (besides A) based on the last observation of the previous company. Therefore, I want to NaN the first observation in each category.

It is easy to get these observations using

```
df.groupby('cat')['ret'].first()
```

but I am a bit lost on how to set them.

```
df.groupby('cat')['ret'].first() = np.NaN
```

and

```
df.loc[df.groupby('cat')['ret'].first(), 'ret']=np.NaN
```

did not lead anywhere.

Comment: you need `pct_change()`

Comment: `pct_change` needs to be carried out within group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for set first value per groups to missing values use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df.loc[~df['cat'].duplicated(), 'ret']=np.NaN
```

But it seems need [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.pct_change.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['cat','date'])
df['ret1'] = df.groupby('cat')['price'].pct_change()
```

Your solution should be changed with [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
df['ret2'] = df['price'] / df.groupby('cat')['price'].shift(1) - 1
print (df)
  cat        date  price      ret1      ret2
0   A  2000-01-01  100.0       NaN       NaN
1   A  2000-02-01  101.0  0.010000  0.010000
2   A  2010-12-01  140.0  0.386139  0.386139
3   B  2000-01-01   10.0       NaN       NaN
4   B  2000-02-01   10.4  0.040000  0.040000
5   B  2010-12-01   11.1  0.067308  0.067308
6   Z  2010-12-01   13.1       NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby('cat')['price'].pct_change()
```